# Custom ActionBar with navigation dropdown list

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I need to add an ActionBar to my application but it has to be customized.
From left to right: custom backbutton, custom dropdown list, custom button, Image in the middle, and two custom buttons on the right.

What is my best approach here? Is it possible using the ActionBar or will I be better off creating this as a Layout?

The minSdk is 14

Comment: What do you mean about 'custom'? Actionbar itself supports customview & theme-styling but at the same time there is some tricky parts either to customize, so one good approach is figure out what you want to implement is already supported in Framework or not. First of all, check related article - [customizing-action-bar](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) and useful tool - [actionbar style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to use ActionBar. Custom dropdown list can be set by

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  /**
   * View displayed inside the Action Bar
   */
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View resultView = convertView;
    if (resultView == null) {
      resultView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_main, null);
    }

    return resultView;
  }

  /**
  * View Displayed inside list of possible options
  */
  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View resultView = convertView;

    if (resultView == null) {
      resultView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_drop_down, null);
    }

    return resultView;
  }

}
```

and then

```
getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(new MyAdapter(), listener);
```

The other things, like custom back icon, you can achieve making styles for your ActionBar.

Answer (score 2):

### I asked this question before and here're you the answer :

You can use a SplitActionBar. Your application suppost to be running on Android 4.0 (API level 14) or higher

the fix is to always have an item in the top bar that prevents the bottom content from ever fitting in there, thus forcing everything into the bottom bar. Look at this sample project from another user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<manifest package="com.commonsware.android.actionbarbc"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
               android:icon="@drawable/cw"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:name=".InflationDemo"
              android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
            android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
</manifest>
```

He used this code for his activity:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(this)
    .inflate(R.layout.conversation_list_actionbar, null);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(v,
        new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT));

mUnreadConvCount = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.unread_conv_count);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar